# Django on Mac OS X: OperationalError 'role "_www" does not exist'. PostgreSQL or Psycopg issue?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, psycopg2, postgresql-9.2

I'm new to web development with Django, so please bear with me and thank you in advance for your help.

I've been using Django's own web server and SQLite while learning. However, now I'm struggling trying to get a more complex setup working for my next project.

My setup (Apache, Python, mod_wsgi, PostgreSQL server, psycopg and Django) should be working fine to the best of my knowledge. I created my Django project and visited localhost on my browser, where I got the "Welcome to Django! It worked!" page. However, when I tried to enable the admin and visited localhost/admin/ I get the following error (note that I can visit this page without errors using Django's own web server):

```
OperationalError at /admin/
FATAL: Role "_www" does not exist
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost/admin/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: FATAL:  role "_www" does not exist
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect, line 178
```

I'm guessing something is not right with PostgreSQL or psycopg, but I'm unsure what exactly. This is how I got here:

1. Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.2) fresh install.
2. Installed Xcode from Mac App Store, then command line tools from Xcode's preferences.
3. Didn't update Apache or Python, I'm using whatever was installed by default (Apache 2.2.22 and Python 2.7.2).
4. Installed mod_wsgi 3.4 from source

   ```
   $ curl -O http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz
   $ tar xvfz mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz
   $ cd mod_wsgi-3.4
   $ ./configure
   $ make
   ```

   (Note: I had to enter the following line for "make" to work:)

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain
   $ make install
   ```
5. Edited httpd.conf, added the following and restarted Apache:

   ```
   LoadModule wsgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
   ```
6. Installed PostgreSQL 9.2.2 by downloading the Postgres.app (http://postgresapp.com) and copying it to my Applications folder.
7. Ran the app, added the following to my ~/.bash_profile (for Terminal to use Postgres.app's psql by default, rather than the one that comes pre-installed on Mac OS X) and then created a new database to use with my django project:

   ```
   PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
   ```
8. Installed psycopg 2.4.6 from source. I downloaded the file, unpacked it and then from the unpacked directory:

   ```
   $ python setup.py install
   ```
9. Installed Django 1.4.3 from source. Created a new project and a new app. Edited the settings.py to uncomment the admin app and enter my database settings (as described on Postgres.app's website: http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_3). The database settings look as follows:

   ```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
       'NAME': 'my_db_name',
       'USER': '',
       'PASSWORD': '',
       'HOST': '',
       'PORT': '',
       }
   }
   ```
10. Edited urls.py to uncomment the admin related lines:

    ```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

    from django.contrib import admin
    admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
    ```
11. Added the following text at the end of https.conf:

    ```
    WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/antubel/Projects/Django/antubel_com/antubel_com/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonPath /Users/antubel/Projects/Django/antubel_com

    <Directory /Users/antubel/Projects/Django/antubel_com>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    ```
12. Restarted Apache. Tried to load localhost/admin/ on my browser and got the error mentioned above.

Please help :)

Thanks,
Dasuevia

Comment: Did you create a postgres user?

Comment: Hi Hedde. Thanks for replying. The Postgres.app I used automatically creates a user and a database using my username ($USER).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your settings file doesn't specify a user to connect to Postgres with, you're trying to connect using the user account that's running your code (and because it's being run by mod_wsgi under Apache, that user is `_www`).

If you're using Postgres.app to run Postgres for you, you will need to set your database `USERNAME` value to the username for your account on the system - so if your username was `foo`, set `USERNAME` to `foo` like so:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'my_db_name',
    'USER': 'foo',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

You can also update your apache config to run your code as a different user - take a look at [WSGIDaemonProcess](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess) in the mod_wsgi docs if you'd like to get that going instead.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I had the feeling it was missing a small detail like that - I only left user empty in the settings because that was the example from Postgres.app. Now I feel a bit silly :P